# Convert multiple columns to one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following structure and data:

```
**Area  |  01-Apr-17  |  02-Apr-17  |  03-Apr-17**
Field_A |     76      |    174      |     123
Field_B |     67      |    414      |     35
```

I need table like this:

```
Area     |    Date      |  Alarm
Field_A  | 01-Apr-17    |    76
Field_A  | 02-Apr-17    |   174
Field_A  | 03-Apr-17    |   123
Field_B  | 01-Apr-17    |    67
Field_B  | 02-Apr-17    |   414
Field_B  | 03-Apr-17    |   358
```

I was trying to adopt pivot function from link below but couldn't get alarm data linked to date column:

[sql server single row multiple columns into one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527543/sql-server-single-row-multiple-columns-into-one-column)

thanks for any help,
S

Answer (score 2):

please check with this query:

```
SELECT
  Area,
  Date,
  Alarm
FROM yourtable
UNPIVOT
(
Alarm
FOR [Date] IN ([01-Apr-17], [02-Apr-17], [03-Apr-17])
) AS P
```

[image]

Comment: Preya, it won't work since I need to generate   Area,  Date, Alarm columns from original data.

Answer (score 1):

Using SQL Server's `PIVOT` is one option, but we can also handle this just using a series of unions:

```
SELECT Area, '01-Apr-17' AS Date, [01-Apr-17] AS Alarm
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT Area, '02-Apr-17', [02-Apr-17]
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT Area, '03-Apr-17', [03-Apr-17]
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Area, Date;
```

Comment: thanks Tim, is that possible to do it with pivot? thanks