# Convert row into column when number of row is not fixed

Tags: sql-server

I want to convert Row into column as shown in below Expected result image.

I have a table and getting data as shown Existing Table image.

Designation Column has dynamic value(Number of value is not fix)

[image]

I tried:

```
 DECLARE  @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

 select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(designation) 
                     from MyTable
                     group by designation  
                     order by designation
             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
             ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') 

 set @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' from 
              (
                 select  SanctionStrength , designation from MyTable                                
             ) x
             pivot 
             (
                 max(SanctionStrength) for designation in (' + @cols + N')
             ) p '                    
     exec sp_executesql @query;
```

I am getting result as expected but only for **SS**.
How can i bind value of AS and VAC together.

[image]

Comment: [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Update in question. thanks Mr. Dale K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to combine columns before pivot.

```
 DECLARE  @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

 select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(designation) 
                     from MyTable
                     group by designation  
                     order by designation
             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
             ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') 

 set @query = N'SELECT Row, ' + @cols + N' from 
              (
                 select ''SS'' Row, SS AS Value , designation from MyTable
                 UNION ALL
                 select  ''AS'' Row, [AS] AS Value , designation from MyTable
                 UNION ALL 
                 select  ''Vac'' Row, Vac AS Value , designation from MyTable 
             ) x
             pivot 
             (
                 max(Value) for designation in (' + @cols + N')
             ) p '                    
     exec sp_executesql @query;
```

Comment: It worked for me :)  Thank you so much Mr. Serkan Arslan.